# I accidentally sent all my tokens to a token contract. Can I get them back?

Tags: tokens

I accidentally sent my tokens to this token contract, is it possible to get them back?

0x33E6Ad33255890e79cE1431FE142e1F3bC1fbEc3

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to say it, But unless you have a private key to that address (Or someone else has) it isn't possible to get your tokens back.